# Step indicator in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm using `react-native-step-indicator` in my project and encountering a few difficulties. Firstly, I couldn't find a way to add descriptions; currently, I can only add titles.

Secondly, why is only the first title positioned behind the indicator? I want all titles to be positioned behind the indicator, not just the first one.

[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    <View style={{ height: '60%' }}>
          <StepIndicator
            customStyles={styles.customStyles}
            currentPosition={activePosition}
            direction="vertical"
            labels={getStepsData?.getSteps?.map((step) => step.name?.en)}
            onPress={(position) => setActivePosition(position)}
          />
```

And here's the style:

```
   customStyles: {
        stepIndicatorSize: 30,
        currentStepIndicatorSize: 40,
        separatorStrokeWidth: 3,
        currentStepStrokeWidth: 5,
        stepStrokeCurrentColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        separatorFinishedColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        separatorUnFinishedColor: Colors.gray,
        stepIndicatorFinishedColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
        stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: Colors.gray,
        stepIndicatorCurrentColor: Colors.white,
        stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 15,
        currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 15,
        stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: '#000000',
        stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: Colors.white,
        stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: Colors.white,
        labelColor: Colors.DarkSlate,
        labelSize: 15,
        currentStepLabelColor: Colors.DeepGreen,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fork the git repository and extend the package with your requirements.

You might add a the capability to pass a fully custom `renderLabel` component to the module which would allow you to any view to

> Secondly, why is only the first title positioned behind the indicator?
> I want all titles to be positioned behind the indicator, not just the
> first one.

It seems that all strings are horizontal centered. The largest string define the container width that’s why it look like only the first string is adjusted left.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can customize the labels? 
Instead of numbers, I want to display a tick(✓) for the finished labels.